# Can not establish a connection between background page and content page

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am writing chrome extension and I am trying to send an message between background pages and content pages.

Problem is that the connection is never established. I even copied the code from google documentations but to no avail.

**Here is my manifest page**

```
{
  "name": "x",
  "description": "x",
  "version": "0.1",
  "permissions": ["contextMenus", "tabs", "notifications"],
   "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "content_script.js"]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["sample.js"]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**My background page**

```
function genericOnClick(info, tab) 
{
       //copy pasted from google tutorials. My own code also didn't work
       chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.farewell);
  });
});


}



// Create a parent item and two children.
var parent1 = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "Rank Trigger", "contexts":["all"]});

var child1 = chrome.contextMenus.create
(
    {"title": "Rank 1", "contexts":["all"], "parentId": parent1, "onclick": genericOnClick}
);
var child2 = chrome.contextMenus.create
(
    {"title": "Rank 2", "contexts":["all"], "parentId": parent1, "onclick": genericOnClick}
);
var child2 = chrome.contextMenus.create
(
    {"title": "Rank 3", "contexts":["all"], "parentId": parent1, "onclick": genericOnClick}
);
```

**Content Script:**

```
//copied from google tutorials
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
  });
```

Any ideas please? Maybe cuz the event is triggered from the context menu but I am not too sure. I am new to JS and chrome extensions programming.

Thanks

Comment: `genericOnClick(e)` is passing the event object as `e`, correct?  Therefore you need `e.target`, or am I mistaken?

Comment: A typo I wrote when editing the code after posting it here...both are "event" in my code. :)

Comment: You should show the code you're using to set the handler

Comment: edited the code as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my code was working as expected and the messages were indeed sent each onClick. Problem was that I was testing it on the wrong page where the contentScript was not injected into.

Dumb mistake on my part...Thanks all for helping

Answer (score 1):

Set up an `onclick` handler on the element and then use `event.currentTarget.outerHTML` to get the HTML of the clicked element.

Comment: Got the following error, do I need to "#include" anything?

Error in event handler for 'contextMenus': Cannot read property 'outerHTML' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'outerHTML' of undefined
    at genericOnClick (chrome-extension://inhjfhckdfpegapembanojbhadkkkdme/sample.js:5:30)
    at contextMenus:42:17
    at chrome.Event.dispatchToListener (event_bindings:387:21)
    at chrome.Event.dispatch_ (event_bindings:373:27)
    at dispatchArgs (event_bindings:249:22)
    at Object.chromeHidden.Event.dispatchEvent (event_bindings:257:7)

Comment: It means that you're not properly referencing the element. When you trigger the onclick function, take the event object that's passed into the function and see if it has a defined currentTarget property.  That currentTarget property should be the reference to the element that you want...

Comment: I think the problem is when sending messages from the background page to the content page. I edited the question again to make it less localized.